# Исключить однобуквенные слова из строки

Tags: c#

Дана строка, в которой содержится осмысленное текстовое сообщение. Слова сообщения разделяются пробелами и знаками препинания. Удалить из сообщения все однобуквенные слова. C#. Есть код, но как я понимаю он не удаляет, а перезаписывает. Нужно обязательно через StringBuilder сделать. Нужно как понимаю через Remove. Но не знаю как это реализовать. Вот исходник

```
using System;
using System.Text;
namespace OOP3
{
    class Class
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите строку состоящую из слов разделенных пробелами");
            string[] words = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                if (words[i].Length != 1)
                    Console.Write(words[i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так вместо печати в консоль добавляйте в StringBuilder: `sb.Append(word[i] + " ")` да и всё. А в конце `Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());`

Comment: Но я бы сделал всё в одну строку через Split, Where и Join, там вообще цикл и if не нужны так то.

Comment: А разве remove не нужно?

Comment: Вы же создаёте новый объект, а не удаляете из имеющегося, поэтому Remove не нужно.

Comment: Удалить из сообщения все однобуквенные слова. Просто в задании удалить

Comment: Нам просто не говорили про Remove. Просто сказали сделать через StringBuilder. Получается данный код подойдет?

Comment: Все. Спасибо большое. Я все понял

Comment: Мой код который я в ответе привёл должен подойти. Удалить из готовой строки в C# вы ничего физически не сможете - строки иммутабельны. Всё-равно придётся собирать новую строку. Так почему бы не собирать её сразу только из нужных элементов, выкидывая лишние. Просто и понятно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ваши ответы

Comment: Через стрингбилдер скорее сего надо не удалять, а добавлять. Хотя, можно последний символ выкидывать ещё - так удобнее будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf, не получится так - разделители остаются: https://ideone.com/ss9M6s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так можно:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
namespace OOP3
{
    class Class
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите строку состоящую из слов разделенных пробелами");
            string[] words = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                if (words[i].Length != 1)
                    sb.Append(word[i] + " ")
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, это я сообразил, спасибо за ответ. Но мне кажется можно с remove сделать или и так удаляет он. Он же не перезаписывает, а именно удаляет сейчас?

Comment: Ну можно конечно сначала собрать в StringBuilder всё, что есть, а потом удалять через Remove, но запутаетесь с индексами и никто так в реальной жизни не делает и не "режет по живому", обычно фильтруют нужные данные и собирают новый объект (в данном случае строку).

Comment: В конце получится лишний пробел. И знаки препинания обрабатываются неверно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да я просто объяснил автору вопроса как сделать, чтобы в принципе заработало. В целом задача вообще несколько по-другому должна решаться, конечно

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, я бы делал так: https://ideone.com/rPV99l

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Console.ReadLine(), @"\b\w\b\W*", ""));
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну, если они уже проходили регулярки... ))

Comment: Нельзя регулировки)

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/svyE2i

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var s = Console.ReadLine();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    Func<int, bool> check = (int i) => i>=0 && i<s.Length && Char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[i]);

    for (var q=0; q<s.Length; )
      if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[q]) && !check(q-1) && !check(q+1))
        while (++q<s.Length && !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[q]));
      else
        sb.Append(s[q++]);

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Не хочешь принять его как верный?

Comment: А это как сделать?

Comment: Слева от ответа есть галочка.

Answer (score 0):

Если проходили Linq, то можно все практически в одну строку:

```
string str = "Проверка а не пример";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string sbitem in str.Split(' ').Where(item => item.Count(char.IsLetterOrDigit) > 1)) sb.Append(sbitem + ' ');
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString().Trim());
```

Если без StringBuilder, то еще меньше строк:

```
string str = "Проверка а не пример";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', str.Split(' ').Where(item => item.Count(char.IsLetterOrDigit) > 1)));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Со StringBuilder'ом в конце получится лишний пробел. В обоих вариантах знаки препинания обрабатываются неверно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Пофиксено =)

Comment: Ну да, получше стало.